# Recoger datos en modal Bootstrap y recuperar datos de PHP al mismo tiempo (AJAX, PHP, MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Recibo datos de un enlace y los muestro en una modal Bootstrap

pagina 1

```
       <a href="pagina" id="id" data-target="#edit-modal">Enlace</a>
```

pagina 2

```
      $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

                 var $modal = $(this),
                     esseyId = e.relatedTarget.id;

                  DatosGlobales = esseyId;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: DatosGlobales,
            url: 'detalles.php?jsoncallback=?',
            success: function(data){

                $modal.find('.edit-content').html(DatosGlobales);      

            }

        });
```

Funciona perfecto. Solamente quiero recuperar los datos de detalles.php y mostrarlos en esa misma modal.

detalles.php

```
    $PostID=$_POST['esseyId'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id='".$PostID."' ";
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "ISO-8859-1"); 
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();
    $cursos = array(); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 

    $nomEns        =$row['NomEns']; 

    $cursos[] = array('nomEns' => $nomEns);

    }   

    $json_string = json_encode($cursos);
    echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $json_string . ');';
```

Cómo puedo mostrar los datos devueltos por php? Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el success de la llamada ajax estas poniendo `$modal.find('.edit-content').html(DatosGlobales);` la variable `DatosGlobales` la inicializas antes de la llamada ajax, si quieres poner lo que te devuelve el php deberías usar `data`
que es lo que devuelve la función del success

```
success: function(data){
```

Saludos!

Comment: Fenomenal. Así es. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Solo una cosa, pretendo además pasar el parametro esseyId al php para la consulta MySql, qué sintaxis debo utilizar?

Comment: Una opción seria que lo mandaras en formato JSON `data:{'esseyId':DatosGlobales}` así te debería quedar esta parte de la llamada ajax. Si te sirvio acepta la respuesta porfas ;)

Comment: Sí, la respuesta inicial me sirvió, muchas gracias. Solo que no entiendo la sintaxis de tu última respuesta, exactamente dónde debo realizar la llamada en JSON?

Comment: Ok, así me funciona: data: "esseyId="+esseyId,